# Create ubuntu docker image with nodeJS 4

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

I need to create a ubuntu docker image with nodeJS 4. What I was doing is this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -yqq python build-essential apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl locales nodejs npm sudo git

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

But does that make sense at all? Installing `apt-get install nodejs npm` and `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -`

And also I have to do `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10`

I would like to get this a bit smaller and smarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I install nodejs in a Debian Jessie container :

```
COPY ./rsrc/nodesource.gpg.key /tmp/nodesource.gpg.key
RUN apt-key add /tmp/nodesource.gpg.key
RUN echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x jessie main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodejs.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I think adding the offical repo list to apt is the best option here.

Edit :

The first two lines add the crypto nodesource key to apt (used later to crypto verify pkg), then add node list to you apt list, update and install your node package

Edit² :

Also, add a dedicated default user into you node image.

Comment: Do I need the first two lines?

Comment: But do I really need crypto verify?

Comment: I think `--allow-unauthenticated` is what you're looking for. **I do not recommend this option**.

Comment: I'm getting this error while trying to build the image: `lstat rsrc/nodesource.gpg.key: no such file or directory`

Comment: Yes, you have to add the gpg.key inside some directory and then use COPY to copy the file into the container